# Возможно ли создать SQL запрос в данном случае?

Tags: sql, firebird

Есть задание: БД посвящена аренде авто. Нужно вывести машину, на которой заработали больше всего денег.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вообщем цена за сутки у авто хранится в таблице CARS.
Тогда чтобы решить задачу нужно рассчитать количество дней, умножить их на стоимость авто, и еще использовать что то типа массива, в котором будут хранится данные. Можно ли сделать это sql запросом, без переменных?

Comment: Если коротко, то: Да, можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
r.avtomobil_id, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,r.data_nachala_arendy,r.data_kontsa_arendy)*c.prise_per_day) [Value]
FROM Rent r
JOIN Cars c on r.avtomobil_id = c.avtomobil_id
GROUP BY r.avtomobil_id
ORDER BY `Value` DESC
```

Только проверьте синтаксис, я в MySQL не очень, а Firebird вроде его диалект использует.

Comment: Спасибо. Суть уловил.

Answer (score 1):

Итоговый ответ:

```
SELECT   FIRST 1
r.AVTOMOBIL_ID, SUM((cast((r.data_kontsa_arendy-r.DATA_NACHALA_ARENDY)+0.5  AS INTEGER))*c.price_per_day)
FROM CAR_RENT r
JOIN Cars c on r.AVTOMOBIL_ID = c.AVTOMOBIL_ID
GROUP BY r.AVTOMOBIL_ID
ORDER BY SUM((cast((r.data_kontsa_arendy-r.DATA_NACHALA_ARENDY)+0.5  AS INTEGER))*c.price_per_day) DESC
```